# Título laboral con mayúsculas iniciales

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Por favor, me gustaría saber si es correcto usar letras mayúsculas al principio de cada palabra en un título laboral como por ejemplo:

> Alberto Pérez, Auditor de Cuentas
>
> María García, Director Financiero
>
> María García, Presidenta Ejecutiva

o la RAE dice que se tiene que escribir:

> Alberto Pérez, Auditor de cuentas
>
> María García, Director financiero
>
> María García, Presidenta ejecutiva

o tal vez:

> Alberto Pérez, auditor de cuentas
>
> María García, director financiero
>
> María García, presidenta ejecutiva

Comment: Casi irónico que tu usuario esté en minúsculas XD

Answer (score 4):

Según la RAE en su [artículo sobre mayúsculas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) en el apartado **4.31** dice que los nombres de los cargos se escriben usualmente con minúsculas pero se escriben con mayúscula cuando se emplean referidas a una persona concreta, sin mención expresa de su nombre propio:

> El Rey inaugurará la nueva biblioteca; El Papa visitará la India en su próximo viaje

El mismo documento en el numeral 6.9 dice:

> **6.9.** Los títulos, cargos y nombres de dignidad como *rey, papa, duque, presidente, ministro,* etc., se escriben con minúscula cuando aparecen acompañados del nombre propio de la persona que los posee, o del lugar o ámbito al que corresponden (*el rey Felipe IV, el papa Juan Pablo II, el presidente de Nicaragua, el ministro de Trabajo*), o cuando están usados en sentido genérico (*El papa, el rey, el duque están sujetos a morir, como lo está cualquier otro hombre*). Existen casos, sin embargo, en que estas palabras pueden escribirse con mayúsculas (→ [4.31](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp#431)).

Según lo anterior, por las normas de la RAE esos títulos deberían escribirse en minúsculas si se han de separar con coma del nombre o con mayúscula inicial si se coloca punto después de los nombres así:

> Alberto Pérez, auditor de cuentas.
>
> Alberto Pérez. Auditor de cuentas.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Cuando respecta al cargo, lo natural es usar las mayúsculas.

> Alberto Pérez, Auditor de Cuentas

En mi opinión personal, encuentro poco *visible* y tal vez visto como no importante dejar el cargo con minúsculas, a saber

> Alberto Pérez, <s>auditor de cuentas.</s>

Aunque de todas formas he visto que comúnmente se acostumbra a poner una sola mayúscula:

> Alberto Pérez, Auditor de cuentas.

Generalmente el cargo siempre va en mayúsculas, el resto a lo que va dirigido (un sustantivo por ejemplo), se suele empezar en minúscula, pero si este quiere destarcase como importante, se puede empezar con mayúscula.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda